# Is a hidden modal login secure over https?

Tags: https, authentication, modal-dialog

I was told this recently: Hiding a modal login window on a page is seen as a security risk.  Or at least it used to be when serving pages over http.

If I want to build a login modal and hide it on the page until invoked.  If the page is served over https are there any security issues and/or associated downgrades in page rank by google because of it?

Comment: What do you mean by 'hiding it' until invoked?

Comment: "display: none" or some such css burying

Comment: I don't see why that would be a security risk, as long as you're not hiding private information. Did the person say why they thought it was a security risk?

Comment: I think the issue was that before the site began to only use https--that google was downgrading them when the site was crawled and it found undisplayed elements with a password field.  That's why I'm thinking it's no longer an issue, but not having done too much on the security side of things, I wanted to be sure I wasn't missing something.  It SEEMS that this is how folks do logins now, by hiding a modal window then invoking it upon some logic path or other.  As long as you're site is only served over https, I don't believe it's an issue

Comment: how does this relate to https/http? Google can still crawl your site and see a hidden password field.

Comment: if google crawls an http site, it will downgrade it as a security risk if it finds a password field because you'd be passing passwords with a non-secured protocol

Comment: OHh right that makes sense. That's all the security risk was then

Comment: Right.  Just found this article talking about the issue.  I just wanted to make sure I wasn't missing anything else, and that https would eliminate the security risk.  https://blog.sucuri.net/2017/08/google-warning-text-input-forms-october-https-ssl.html